in view path, can I replace tid with token:name
What I have, the view path bild the path with token id's.
such like:
excample.com/view?token=555
maybe with [node:field_token:entity:name] or {{ node:field_token:entity:name }} ?
with better_exposed_filters I have replaced in the path the "token"
how can I replace the 555 with the token:name?
thank you for your time
